# Aspect-oriented vs explicit style in Python

Tags: python, comparative-review, aspect-oriented

[Readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), but is very subjective. The following snippets are equivalent in functionality and turn a generator iterator into a chunked HTTP response in Flask. Which of those two patterns is more Pythonic, readable and convenient?

A) Aspect style with function decorators that change the return value:

```
@app.route('/')
@flask_response_decorator
@optional_streaming_decorator
@progress_log_decorator
def index() -> Iterator:
    """Index page, optionally HTTP chunk-streamed and formatted."""
    return Foo.get_instance().are_changes_locked()
```

or

B) explicit decorators within the function body

```
@app.route('/')
def index() -> flask.Response:
    """Index page, optionally HTTP chunk-streamed and formatted."""
    response = Foo.get_instance().are_changes_locked()
    return flask.Response(optional_iterator_to_stream(iterator_to_progress_log(response)))
```

Comment: Around here, we generally don't like brevity.

Comment: I added docstrings. The code above is now exactly as it is in my project, except from the `Foo` class, which is irrelevant for this example.

Comment: You say yourself that it is subjective, that IMHO means its not a good fit for the kind of "objective" QA-style system here. In addition, you did not provide a lot of code to judge the code/differences in a greater context, which makes this question tend even more to the [off-topic](/help/dont-ask) side of things.

Comment: I don't see how this question could possibly be off-topic. It is matched by the first point of on-topic examples: "If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas: Application of best practices and design pattern usage (...)". This question is about the usage of decorators for transforming the return value of a Flask view function and I provided a real piece of code I am using in production.

Answer (score 1):

> Pythonic, readable and convenient

are all subjective and open to debate, even though "Pythonic" is less so than the others. That said, a simplified version may be illustrative. Comparing

```
@foo
@bar
def baz(value: T) -> T:
    return value
```

to

```
def baz(value: T) -> FooT:
    return foo(bar(value))
```

there are two issues with the former:

1. The final return type is now hidden in `foo`.
2. It is easy to confuse the layering - is `baz(value)` equivalent to `foo(bar(baz(value)))` or `bar(foo(baz(value)))` (or even `baz(foo(bar(value)))` in case of a novice)? Nested decorators come up so rarely that I would have to look at the documentation to be absolutely sure whether they were in the right sequence.

There seems to be two situations where multi-level decorators would be fine:

1. If they pass through the return value unchanged. A logger would be a typical example.
2. If the decorators are [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), that is, their order doesn't matter for the outcome.